# Extracting a song information from a downloaded file

Tags: python, django, audio

When I download a song in my android phone, the song gets included in my music player along with song name, singer name, movie name and also a song logo. I want to extract the same information for a song downloaded on my laptop. I am making a music web app with django and I need a song's information to be displayed.

Comment: what is the format of the songs that you handle?

Comment: @Dekel mp3 format

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.  Please post your code and describe the specific problem.